# Compress hash output (from hex to "higher" representation)

Tags: php, math, hash, base-conversion

I have a 40 character long SHA1 value that is stored in an indexed column in a InnoDB table. To shorten the index I want it to be "compressed" without increasing the risk for a collision.

```
<?php

$a = "875e5d6959da75400c837a79ecca23d79b40e7a5";

$b = base_convert($a, 16, 36);

echo $b; // ft92zicmcfks08088wk0oow44oso8gk

?>
```

It this solution ok? And why can't I convert to base64, it gives me the following warning:

`Warning:  base_convert(): Invalid "to base" (64) in...`

Comment: Oh "Base64" encoding is not like the "base 10" we say when we mean decimal and "base 16" for hex or "base 2" for binary. Those kind of bases generally only go from 2 to 36 in most programming languages.

Comment: Ok, I removed the additional topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because as per manual of **[`base_convert`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php)**

> ... `tobase` **have to be between 2 and 36, inclusive**. Digits in
>   numbers with a base higher than 10 will be represented with the
>   letters a-z, with a meaning 10, b meaning 11 and z meaning 35. The
>   case of the letters doesn't matter, i.e. number is interpreted
>   case-insensitively.

Comment: This will get you to 31 characters if you use base 36. If you write your own code and use base85 you can get this down to 25 characters.